# Creating exe from multiple perl files

Tags: perl, user-interface, exe, pack

I have a set of 4 perl files. The main file calls the other three files as:
system("perl file2.pl"); (all the files are in the same folder)
I have to create a single exe file from all the four .pl files such that i am able to call the other 3 files using just the main script. I have tried creating an exe using perl dev kit. but it works only if the files are present in the same directory as the exe.
Please suggest some way to make an independent exe that is able to call the 3 files.

*I dont know if this is important or not but all the files have GUI.

Comment: As you are calling `system("perl file.pl")` you will not be able to create an exe containing all three files without magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either include the code of all files in a single file instead of using `system()` call, or turn other 3 perl files into modules and import them in your main perl script. Otherwise, the generated executable will call `system()` as you do in your original script.